# Reset collection in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

**Block 1:**
initialize method works fine as expected but when "SelectIndustry"  is called from **Block 3** **this.query is undefined**

```
ComplienceCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Complience,

initialize: function () {

    _.bindAll(this, 'selectFeaturesCallback');
     vent.bind("onSelectIndustry", this.SelectIndustry);
    if(industrylookup == null)
    {
        industrylookup = "http://hostname/ArcGIS/rest/services/sss/MapServer/2?f=json";
    }
    this.queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask(industrylookup);
    dojo.connect(this.queryTask, 'onComplete', this.selectFeaturesCallback);
    this.query = new esri.tasks.Query();
    this.query.returnGeometry = false;
    this.query.where = '1=1';
    this.query.outFields = ['*'];
    this.queryTask.execute(this.query);
    },
selectFeaturesCallback: function (featureSet) {
    var item=_.pluck(featureSet.features, "attributes");
    this.reset(item);
},
 SelectIndustry: function (oid) {


        this.query.where = '1=1';

      this.queryTask.execute(this.query);
}
```

});

**Block 2:**
This is called on page load with other backbone functions

```
    vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
    complienceList = new ComplienceCollection();
```

**Block 3:**
Calling from plain javascript file

```
    vent.trigger("onSelectIndustry",indutrytype);
```

Comment: Try binding this to SelectIndustry also.
 _.bindAll(this, 'SelectIndustry');

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the specific of `this` in javascript which could be different depending on calling method. Instead of

```
vent.bind("onSelectIndustry", this.SelectIndustry);
```

try this:

```
var self = this;
vent.bind("onSelectIndustry", function( oid ){ self.SelectIndustry( oid ) });
```

If this works you can beautify your call by something like `$.proxy` or similar.

Comment: Or `vent.bind("onSelectIndustry", this.SelectIndustry, this)` if you want to avoid an unnecessary function wrapper.